# How do I uses Python's multiprocessing.Value method with .map()?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, undefined

I'm testing some code using multiprocessing to try to understand it, but I'm struggling to get the .Value to work. What am I doing wrong, it says p doesn't exist?

here's my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value
from ctypes import c_int
if __name__ =="__main__":
    p=Value(c_int,1)


def addone(a):
    print(a)

    with p.get_lock():
        print(p.value)
        p.value += 1
if __name__ =="__main__":
    with Pool() as po:
        po.map(addone,range(19))
    print(p.value)
```

And I get this error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(I removed this)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\(I removed this)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\(I removed this)\Desktop\Python\make\multiTest.py", line 10, in addone
    with p.get_lock():
NameError: name 'p' is not defined
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File (I removed this), line 15, in <module>
    po.map(addone,range(19))
  File "C:\Users\(I removed this)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\(I removed this)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: name 'p' is not defined
```

What should I do?

Comment: Remove the first `if __name__ =="__main__":` and it should work fine... probably

Comment: Specifically, remove the FIRST `if`, so the `p=Value...` is executed in every process.

Comment: Google "global variable python multiprocessing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want a single instance of the shared value, `p`, to be operated on by the pool processes executing your worker function, `addone`. The way to do this is to use the *initalizer* and *initargs* arguments of the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` class to initialize a global variable, `p`, in each pool process with the shared value created by the main process. Passing explicitly `p` to a multiprocessing pool worker function as an additional argument will not work; this will result in the cryptic error: **RuntimeError: Synchronized objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance**.

```py
def init_pool_processes(shared_value):
    global p
    p = shared_value

def addone(a):
    print(a)

    with p.get_lock():
        print(p.value)
        p.value += 1

if __name__ =="__main__":
    from multiprocessing import Pool, Value
    from ctypes import c_int

    p = Value(c_int, 1)
    with Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(p,)) as po:
        po.map(addone, range(19))
    print(p.value)
```

Comment: Do I need to do Pool.close if I use a with statement?

Comment: No. When you exit the block there will be an implicit call to `po.terminate()`. which will kill all running pool processes. If you want to wait for the processes to actually be gone, you can then call `po.join()` but since your program is ending up anyway, I don't see much point.